# Simple way to view who is currently connected to my AP. Linux Network-manager or nmcli

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networkmanager, wifi-hotspot, nmcli

I have set up a hotspot with network-manager in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I used these instructions https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235775/fine-tuning-network-manager-in-ap-mode to configure the hotspot to to run in AP mode (as opposed to ad-hoc). I would like to know the details of who is connected wirelessly. It seems to me that hotspot mode is not very well documented in network-manager or nmcli.